# SMTPTransport as private static for class that implements MessageDrivenBean and MessageListener

Tags: java, smtp, jakarta-mail

If I use SMTPTransport (http://java.sun.com/products/javamail/javadocs/com/sun/mail/smtp/SMTPTransport.html) as private static object for class that implements MessageDrivenBean and MessageListener, will it be thread safe or are there some possible error situations?

Comment: what is `SMTPTransport`?

Comment: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport

Comment: http://java.sun.com/products/javamail/javadocs/com/sun/mail/smtp/SMTPTransport.html

Comment: And what is `MessageDrivenBean` and `MessageListener` (I think I have at least a dozen of the later on the classpath of my current project)

Comment: javax.ejb.MessageDrivenBean and javax.jms.MessageListener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like SMTPTransport is a thread-safe object.
So, you should be able to use it from any thread.
Though you should not be too optimistic about this.  I've seen too few API which were ready to be used from different threads without problems :(